# maven-pmd-plugin external custom ruleset doesn't work

Tags: maven, pmd

I'm using this in my pom in the reporting section:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>http://serverxxx/pmd-java.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

somehow it doesn't work. When I use the rules directly instead of a custom ruleset via http it work fine. I use pmd:pmd and the section is also in the build section of the pom...

Logs:
16:11:05 [INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:cpd (default-cli) @ online-news ---
16:11:05 mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1(default-cli)
16:11:05 [DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern cpd.xml
16:11:05 [DRY] Parsing 1 files in D:\build\hudson\jobs\xxx migration-maven-3 CI\workspace\migration-maven-3\application\online-modules\online-news\target
16:11:06 [DRY] Successfully parsed file D:\build\hudson\jobs\xxx migration-maven-3 CI\workspace\migration-maven-3\application\online-modules\online-news\target\cpd.xml of module News with 31 warnings.
16:11:06 [DRY] Computing warning deltas based on reference build #13
16:11:06 mojoStarted org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2(default-cli)

Comment: could you provide the relevant part of your logs

Comment: It is working with version 2.6 of the pmd plugin. Using this instead